# chrome API connection between web page and extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

According to the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) of the chrome message passing API, you can pass messages between an extension and a web page. Is there a way to open connections between a web page and an extension?

Comment: It's written in the documentation you linked! Please be more specific with your problem.

Comment: Opps you are correct